# SQL-запрос. Заменять n на текст в запросе или в php после запроса?

Tags: php, mariadb

Делаю БД для кафе. Есть таблица remote_orders. 4 поля в ней почти одинаковы: First_item, Second_item, Third_item, Fourth_item. Они хранят индекс товара (связаны с таблицей menu). В каком месте системы будет грамотнее заменить индексы на человеческие названия? Из запроса не получилось, это слишком сложно, и получается обращение к именам по четыре раза за запрос. Может, в php-коде запросом доставать эти четыре поля и заменять числа на слова оттуда, одиножды обратившись к строкам n и запомнив их в массиве php? Как это вообще делается обычно?

Comment: Это делается СОВСЕМ по-другому. С помощью таблицы order_items, в которую пишется ЛЮБОЕ количество товаров для заказа, а не только от 1 до 4. На текст заменяется в запросе с помощью JOIN